# SQL query: single row per group

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get one result for each group but it return more than one. Here my statement

```sql
SELECT in_id, in_name, ig_id, ig_name, di_name, iv_id, iv_reading, iv_date, iv_time
FROM `instruments`
JOIN instrument_group ON ig_id = in_igid
LEFT JOIN instrument_reading ON iv_inid = in_id AND date(iv_date) = date(20130301)
RIGHT JOIN dam_info ON di_id = ig_diid
WHERE ig_id = in_igid
```

and here the output
[image]

as you can see above, the `in_id` 6 is having two result and i only want one which is the latest result of table `instrument_reading`.

*Update*: Table schema

[image]

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT in_id, in_name, ig_id, ig_name, di_name, iv_id, iv_reading, iv_date, iv_time
FROM `instruments`
JOIN instrument_group ON ig_id = in_igid
LEFT JOIN (SELECT iv_id, iv_inid, iv_reading,iv_date, iv_time FROM instrument_reading     WHERE date(iv_date) = date(20130301) ORDER BY iv_time DESC LIMIT 1) as latestDt ON latestDt.iv_inid = in_id
LEFT JOIN dam_info ON di_id = ig_diid
WHERE ig_id = in_igid
```

i used this as temporary solution. I open this to you if you have better approach